# PyCharm doesn't use selected virtualenv

Tags: django, macos, virtualenv, pycharm

PyCharm seems to ignore the configured `virtualenv`,
and use the base interpreter instead.

In my project at `/Users/janos/dev/git/github/bashoneliners` I have a `virtualenv` subdirectory, strictly with my project's dependencies installed in it:

```
$ . virtualenv/bin/activate
(virtualenv)janos at kronos in ~/dev/git/github/bashoneliners on master
$ pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /Users/janos/dev/git/github/bashoneliners/virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
(virtualenv)janos at kronos in ~/dev/git/github/bashoneliners on master
$ pip freeze
Django==1.9
Markdown==2.6.5
PyJWT==1.4.0
defusedxml==0.4.1
oauthlib==1.0.3
pep8==1.6.2
pyflakes==1.0.0
python-social-auth==0.2.13
python3-openid==3.0.9
requests==2.9.1
requests-oauthlib==0.6.0
six==1.10.0
tweepy==3.5.0
```

But if I add this `virtualenv` as **Project Interpreter** in PyCharm,
it shows completely different packages:

[image]

These packages are the same as in my system's base interpreter `/opt/local/bin/python`. This drives me nuts, I really need to use the packages from the `virtualenv`, *not* from my system.

This is with PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.3.

I didn't have this problem before with older versions of PyCharm.
I tried creating a completely new `virtualenv`,
both on the command line and using PyCharm,
and invalidating caches and restarting, but nothing seems to work.
PyCharm always shows the same list of packages,
and the packages of the `virtualenv`.
Even if I create an empty `virtualenv` within PyCharm,
it doesn't start empty, but filled with the same list of packages.

My project works perfectly when I run things on the command line,
such as running Django management commands, unit tests, everything.
I only have problems in PyCharm.

If I try to install packages, for example Django,
using PyCharm,
I get this error:

[image]

Of course permission denied on `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages`, that's the system interpreter.
It should be trying to install the package there,
but in `/Users/janos/dev/git/github/bashoneliners/virtualenv`.

Clearly it's not using `pip` from the `virtualenv`, but from the system.
I need to make to use the one from the `virtualenv`.

Comment: Have you logged an issue with jetbrains youtrack?

Comment: Are you excluding global packages from your virtual environments?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not that I know of. I create my envs with `virtualenv --distribute virtualenv`. But I'm starting to think that the problem might have something to do with the way I installed Python (macports, but don't remember the details). For example, outside a virtual env, `pip` is out of sync with `python`. That is, in a `python` shell I cannot import the packages shown by `pip freeze`. Perhaps if I sort that out first (as I very well should), maybe PyCharm will magically start working too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I cleaned up my system. `python`, `pip`, `virtualenv` are all properly synced, using the same Python installation now. This didn't help with PyCharm, so my suspicion was wrong. I guess it's a bug then. I didn't have such problems with PyCharm in the past.

Comment: Good point @Sayse, it seems it's already logged: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18074

Comment: Good to hear! I know from experience too that they're (normally) very good at fixing issues quickly

Answer (score 2):

This is logged as a bug in the issue tracking system of JetBrains,
so hopefully it will get sorted out soon.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18074

A possible workaround is to fall back to a previous version of PyCharm:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Previous+PyCharm+Releases

As of 2016 Jan 6, `virtualenv` works fine for me in PyCharm 4.5.4.
Some of the `virtualenv` previously registered using PyCharm 5.0.3 appear invalid, but that's fine. I actually deleted all registered interpreters and re-added only the `virtualenv` I needed.

An odd thing with this older version is that sometimes PyCharm shows the incorrect Python version (2.7 instead of 3.5), but it shows the correct list of modules as per the `virtualenv`, and the editor doesn't show build errors, so the Python version mixup doesn't seem to cause problems (just a bit scary).

Comment: Thanks for the tracker link. I report the same issue, python installed with macports. Actually, the workaround for me was to install and select python2.7. With 2.7 works as expected, so this is clearly a 3.x issue (tried with 3.3 and 3.5)